# What is release model in salesforce if changeset can't be rolled back

Tags: deployment, change-set, release

I am new to salesforce. As documented in salesforce, What is release model in salesforece if changset can't be rolled back? Can we backup the data and the customisation by myself and rolled back my some tools if salesforce does not provide this functionality.

Deployment is a one-way transaction
A change set is deployed in a single transaction. If the deployment is unable to complete for any reason, the entire transaction is rolled back. After a deployment completes successfully, all changes are committed to your organization and the deployment can’t be rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question to ask is what is the risk of an erroneous deployment?  If human life is at risk, then more sophisticated rollback strategies may be required.

That said, in most CRM applications, the consequences of an error are not that severe and can be mitigated by having superb regression tests in your testmethods - that is, testmethods that do more than just code coverage.  Such testmethods do asserts to validate actual results against expected results for a range of inputs.

As you know, any changeset deployment to PROD will run your regression tests (testmethods) and all must pass before the deployment succeeds.

This answer is not to invalidate version control-based deployment models but rather to suggest that time and energy should go into testmethods to ensure the database is updated properly.  Validating the UI is a different matter and tools such as Selenium may be useful if you need a regression-based model.

Every SFDC org is different - some are maintained by 'one man bands' and changesets can be appropriate; others are team-based efforts and version control based deployments make more sense.